# Lambda function needs to use key for dependency in the code, where to store it?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have some code such as this which will run inside of Lambda:

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;

Parse.initialize("Your App Id", "Your JavaScript Key");

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.find({
  success: function(users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
      console.log(users[i].get('username'));
    }
  }
});
```

The code needs an API key to work. Is it safe to just put the key directly into the code or should I store it somewhere else, and if so where? I am concerned if it needs to be stored externally, this will cause overhead as I need to make a network call every time to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't put it in the code. One cheap and elegant solution is to use the Key Management Services offered by AWS. Just few lines of code to retrieve your key from AWS KMS. It costs $0.03 for every 10000 requests and each key storage costs $1/month.

[AWS Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/)

It is integrated with AWS Lambda too.

Edit: See this SO link on how to use it: [AWS Lambda: How to store secret to external API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372278/aws-lambda-how-to-store-secret-to-external-api)

Comment: Thanks! So my function will still though have to make a network call to KMS everytime the function is called though correct, or is it cached?

Comment: I do not think it is cached. You can check the link I posted.

Comment: Regarding caching, check this tread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=686261 specifically this response from Amazon: "Global" code (outside your handler) is initialized once per container (and then not called again). That's a great place to do any dynamic initialization, such as setting up global variables that you want to use throughout the lifetime of the container (i.e., across multiple requests). You can retrieve values from Amazon S3, Amazon DynamoDB, or other sources.